# Client components in turborepo cause error

Tags: next.js, turborepo, tsup

I am trying to build a Turborepo with react client components in a separate [internal ui package](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/sharing-code/internal-packages).

Unfortunately, `tsup` removes the `use client`  directive at the top of the `ui` packages, which are needed for nextjs. Message:

> Module level directives cause errors when bundled, "use client" in
> "dist/Test.mjs" was ignored.

Minimal reproduction sandbox, showing the error: https://shorturl.at/noxzI

Any tips on how to fix this?

---

**EDIT 1:**

New URL: https://rb.gy/gubwk

---

**EDIT 2:**

The above minimal repo produces the following error message:

> TypeError: a.default.createContext is not a function

Based on other SO answers, that is likely because `use client` is missing. If you add `use client` to the built Test chunk in the dist folder, that error goes away and is replaced by this error:

> TypeError: styled_components__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.div is not
> a function

---

**EDIT 3:**

Just a side-note that the error happens regardless of whether the component is a js file (e.g. `Test`) or a tsx file (e.g. `Card`). Somehow webpack does not include the `styled-component` package.

Comment: Link to shorturl doesn't work.

Comment: @Jaryn Added a new one. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Keep in mind that turbopack is still in beta and errors as well as inconsistencies are to be expected. Try using the default bundler and see if the error persists.

Comment: @FabioNettis I tried rollup, unfortunately with a similar result.

Comment: Again, try the default bundler and see if the error persists. Rollup is not the default bundler, webpack is.

Comment: @fabioNettis Sorry, I don't follow you. Default bundler of what? Turborepo has examples that use tsup for the packages folder (like the tailwind example), as well as an example using rollup. I haven't tested all the examples, but I am guessing the others also use one of those two.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have misunderstood you, I thought this was about using turbopack with Next.js. Then I would have recommended using webpack.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete the dist folder in the ui package.
2. Edit your /packages/ui/tsup.config.js file with the following:

```
    import { defineConfig, Options } from "tsup";
    
    export default defineConfig((options: Options) => ({
      banner: {
        js: `"use client"`,
      },
      // treeshake: true,
      splitting: true,
      entry: ["./**/*.tsx"],
      format: ["esm"],
      dts: true,
      minify: true,
      clean: true,
      external: ["react"],
      ...options,
    }));
```

Note the banner option telling tsup to not remove the **"use client"**, and I noticed that treeshake was removing "too much" so you can delete/remove that option. With the following config I was able to build the project without any errors.

3. run build script again!

Comment: Adding banner like this will also affect Server Components, turning Server Components into Client Components as well.

Here is a [PR](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/pull/6307) currently being reviewed that only injects "use client" to js files inside the `src/client` directory.




PS: In my PR, tailwind is used, so the client component have to be compiled along with server components in order for tailwind to pick up the classes. If you are not using tailwind, you can follow this example [here] to build server and client components separately.

Comment: @williamli I added a comment on your PR with an issue I encountered, trying your first approach. Thanks for the efforts on this.

Comment: @Magnus thanks for the comment. I have resolved the issue in an update in PR.